# Trouble to run commands after changing user password with home directory encryption

Tags: server, ssh, password, encryption, postgresql

I needed to change a server password, done that by `passwd`. Thing is, this Ubuntu Server installation uses the home encryption aparently. Once I changed the password, after some package update, the server doesn't show the  files just after login in via SSH, as before. To access user home files, I have to `ecryptfs-mount-private`, then type in the older user password, then `cd /home/<user>`, and finally, to get all aliases and styling running `source .bashrc`.

I don't mind to do that, but today I tried to use `psql` command to interact with local PostgreSQL server, but the message keep showing:

> shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access
>   parent directories: No such file or directory could not identify
>   current directory: No such file or directory Password for user
>   postgres:  could not
>   identify current directory: No such file or directory
>   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql: could not find own program
>   executable

I can work with `psql` if I go to `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/`, but I would like to retrieve the ease of just typing `psql` from anywhere and things work.

How do I change the encryptation password so it would be the same as the user then running automatically as I log in by SSH?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found this answer here in AskUbuntu:

[Will changing password re-encrypt my home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33730/will-changing-password-re-encrypt-my-home-directory)

What I had to do was:

```
ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```